# Questionnaire analysis and grouping responses

Tags: regression, spss, survey, unbalanced-classes

I want to know if the creative process engagement (CPE) is related to creativity. I don't know how to analyze the questionnaire. I will be collecting data for CPE with Zhang and Bartal's (2010) 11-item scale and creativity with Shin and Zhoe's (2007) four-item scale. Responses will be recorded on 5-point Likert scales.

I know how to input data into SPSS. What I don't know is how to analyze it. Should I enter data for each variable in separate files and analyze it (e.g. creativity q1-q4 in one file and creative process engagement q1-q11 in another file)? How will these questions tell me if respondent thinks there is creativity or not and if respondent engages in creative process or not? Will I have a binary value after analysis (0,1) for each respondent? (i.e. if n=10 will i have 10 values for variable say for creativity)

Second, data on creativity is provided by supervisors and data on creative process engagement is provided by employees. Now this means I'll end up with 3-8 (depending on firm) responses for cpe for each response of creativity (i.e. if y=1 then x=3. supervisor having 3 workers). What should I do if I want to use regression? Can the answers of workers (x=3) grouped (x=1) so I have 1 response?

Comment: Analyzing your questionnaire highly depends on your research questions and objectives especially. From experience not all questions existing in a questionnaire are in line with the research objectives. However you may find that demographic data like age, marital status, gender, etc., are equally important to reflect in some question opinions. In SPSS, try to merge your data input into orthogonal data sets. That way it will be easier to analyze your questionnaire, as this groups many queries into one individual field.